# How to indent a line which overflows into a second line

Tags: indentation

I have some text which I want to indent slightly, the third line keeps overflowing into the second line which is fine but loses the indentation. I've tried a few of the options detailed here but all have the same result. I haven't used itemise because the gaps between each line were too large and I couldn't find a workaround which reduced this gap enough.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm, right=30mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\title{Markets}

\newcommand{\forceindent}{\leavevmode{\parindent=1em\indent}}

\begin{document}

\forceindent $\diamond$ News: Breaking news\\
\forceindent $\diamond$ Non-exchange\\
\forceindent $\diamond$ Corporate fundamentals such as corporate actions (dividends, splits, earnings etc.), financials such as historical net income, debt; as well as non financial data, such as management.\\
\forceindent $\diamond$ Global economic.\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  What is the aim here?  Why are you not using an `itemize` with custom labels?  The `enumitem` package gives good control over indentation etc.

Comment: It looks like you'd be better using `itemize`, with each line `\item[$\diamond$] News:Breaking news` etc.  Or better still a customised `itemize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, by use of the `enumitem` package you can write your items as list:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm, right=30mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\title{Markets}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}[label= $\diamond$, wide=1em, leftmargin=1em]
\item   News: Breaking news 
\item   Non-exchange 
\item   Corporate fundamentals such as corporate actions (dividends, splits, earnings etc.), financials such as historical net income, debt; as well as non financial data, such as management. 
\item   Global economic. 
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `[wide=1em, leftmargin=1em]` is shorter for the same layout ;o)

Comment: @Bernard, thank you very much for the point. I correct my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for hanging identation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm, right=30mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\title{Markets}

\newcommand{\forceindent}{\par\leavevmode\hangindent=4em\hangafter=1\indent}

\begin{document}

Normal text 

\forceindent $\diamond$ News: Breaking news
\forceindent $\diamond$ Non-exchange
\forceindent $\diamond$ Corporate fundamentals such as corporate actions (dividends, splits, earnings etc.), financials such as historical net income, debt; as well as non financial data, such as management.
\forceindent $\diamond$ Global economic.

Normal text

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Notice that I have also removed all the `\\` at the end of the lines)

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the gaps?

Comment: I am not sure to which gaps you are referring to...

Comment: Between each line, sorry.

Comment: I have updated the answer. THe extra space is from `parskip`, I think.